# Scanning through all files in a folder and returning path

Tags: python

so basically im trying to go through all the files in folder and return the path. this is my folder structure with baby_names containg the information im trying to get

```
FOLDER: (folder)
———main.py
———contents: (package)
——————babynames.py
——————baby_names: (folder)
—————————yob1880.txt
—————————yob1881.txt 
——————helper_functions: (package)
—————————hf.py
```

this is my code:

```
def retrieve_files(file_extension):
    """
    Go through folders in the Assignment 8, return a list
    containing the path and file name for every file with the specified extension.

    Args:
        file_extension (str)

    Returns:
        list: A list of file paths and names matching the specified extension.
    """
    file_paths = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("Assignment8"):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(file_extension):
                file_paths.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    return file_paths
```

but when i tun it its saying that its not retrieving any files. ive also tried adjusting the file path to: Desktop/python 2/FOLDER. this is still not working

Comment: Please read [mre]. We need to see how you run the code, what output you get, and what output you expect instead.

Comment: If you just want to find all files with an extension, use `glob.glob()` instead of writing your own loop.

Comment: But my best **guess** is that Python does not find the named folder at all, because it is not contained with the current working directory. Using something like `Desktop/` etc. will not work unless you also include a **complete, absolute path to the Desktop**, unless you **happen** to start the program from your base user folder (`C:/Users/your_username`).

Comment: @Barmar while this is fine advice, that approach doesn't help solve the problem - it will just encounter the same problem, for the same reason. (At least, if my guess is correct.)

Comment: Looks like a case for something like `pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.glob('**/*.py')` in `main.py`. That will work relative to your FOLDER.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**:

As @s3dev mentioned, I tried the path "N:/Code" and it worked. So modifying the answer accordingly.

---

Just ensure you're running the program from the directory where the "Assignments" directory is present and not from another location.

I ran your code and it worked for me. The issue is probably with the path you're giving or the location from where you're running your program.

Below is the complete code that I ran

```
import os


def retrieve_files(file_extension):
    """
    Go through folders in the Assignment 8, return a list
    containing the path and file name for every file with the specified extension.

    Args:
        file_extension (str)

    Returns:
        list: A list of file paths and names matching the specified extension.
    """
    file_paths = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("N:\\Code"):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(file_extension):
                file_paths.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    return file_paths


jfiles = retrieve_files(".java")
for file in jfiles:
    print(file)
```

Below is my PowerShell snippet

```
PS N:\Code> python dfs.py
N:\Code\Java-Programs\hackerrank\minimum-swaps-2\Solution.java
N:\Code\Java-Programs\leetcode\contains-duplicate\Solution.java
N:\Code\Java-Programs\leetcode\decode-string\Solution.java
```

Comment: This statement “If you're on Windows, you must use backslashes in the path.” is **false**.  Even on Win, the path separator (in Python) can be a forward slash. In fact, to some this is preferable as it’s consistent with other path separators.

Comment: And ideally, you use `pathlib.Path` anyway to be OS independent

Comment: You're right @s3dev